# Flask outside application context after trivial change

Tags: flask

I have an app that worked fine, then I added a few lines of code that are logically identical to some code that was already there, and suddenly I am getting out of application context errors.

The code is trying to get a new configuration variable from current_app.config. When it worked it was already getting such variables.

This works, observe that `current_app.config['SECRET_KEY']` therefore works.

```
**config.py**
...
class Config(object):
    ...
    SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY') or \
        'yaP5vdVON2IlssoL3OZEo41P2MXJo6hx'
    ...

**models.py**
...
from flask import current_app
...

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'app'
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    )
    tennant_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('_constants.tennant_id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    identity_id = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True)
    ...
    def get_reset_password_token(self, expires_in=600):
        return jwt.encode(
            {'reset_password': self.user_id, 'exp': time() + expires_in},
            current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'],
            algorithm='HS256').decode('utf-8')
```

*The following does not work*, observe that there is no apparent difference in the way the config variables `RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOW_TYPE` and `MESSAGE_POST_TYPE` are handled.

Furthermore I used to use explicitly declared versions of these variables in the code, so the code worked!

```
**config.py**
...
class Config(object):
    ...
    SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY') or \
        'yaP5vdVON2IlssoL3OZEo41P2MXJo6hx'
    ...
    MESSAGE_POST_TYPE = 2
    RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOW_TYPE = 1
    ...

**models.py**
...
from flask import current_app
...

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'app'
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    )
    tennant_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('_constants.tennant_id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    identity_id = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True)
    ...
    def get_reset_password_token(self, expires_in=600):
        return jwt.encode(
            {'reset_password': self.user_id, 'exp': time() + expires_in},
            current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'],
            algorithm='HS256').decode('utf-8')
    ...       
    def followed_posts(self):
        followed = Message.query.join(
            Relationship, 
            (Relationship.related_user_id == Message.sender_id)). \
            filter(Relationship.user_id == self.user_id). \
            filter(Relationship.relationship_type_id == current_app.config['RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOW_TYPE']). \
            filter(Message.message_type_id == current_app.config['MESSAGE_POST_TYPE'])
        own = Message.query.filter_by(
            sender_id = self.user_id,
            message_type_id = current_app.config['MESSAGE_POST_TYPE'])
        return followed.union(own).order_by(Message.timestamp.desc())
```

I have tried everything! In particular: -

1. I went back to an older working version of the code, manually added
   a config variable to the Config, manually added a usage of that
   variable read from the config into models.py, and it worked! I can
   see no differences between the code!
2. In my new non-working code I reverted the two new config variables
   back to being explicitly declared, the code ran until it hit the
   next `current_app.config` variable *after* the `SECRET_KEY`,
   in other words `current_app.config` works for `SECRET_KEY`
   but not for `RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOW_TYPE` and
   `MESSAGE_POST_TYPE`.

Obviously I must be doing something pretty dumb. Can someone just point me to anywhere or any reason why this may happen. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the correct value for `SECRET_KEY`? That is a built-in flask config value, so it will "work" (not raise an Attribute Error) but not necessarily return the correct value if you aren't loading your `Config` object correctly. Ca you confirm the value for `SECRET_KEY` matches the value in your `Config` object?

Comment: In the older working app yes the secret key passes from a .env file into my config file then onto the app, and the app displays the same secret key. In the new not-working app, I changed the code as described in new comments above and it appears to be able to read the config secret key but not the other new config variables.

Comment: To highlight the bizarre behaviour, in a single program ```current_app.config['SECRET_KEY']``` works but ```current_app.config['MESSAGE_POST_TYPE']``` causes the code to abort saying *outside application context*. Both config variables are defined identically. If I supply the message post type directly the code works.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very satisfactory answer but I will explain what I did, if anyone has a better answer feel free to post.

1. I created a new class in my config.py module called Globals.
2. I moved all the new config variables from Config to Globals. After
   this Config was back to the way it was when the app worked and
   Globals is a new class.
3. I updated all my code to get the new config variables from Globals
   and all the original ones from Config. So I added an import for
   Globals and left the import of current_app alone.
4. I changed the names of variables to refer to either Global config
   variables or Config variables as appropriate.
5. I did not move any code, or make *any* other changes.

Although this shouldn't have worked it did.

To further test things I added some dummy config variables to the Config class, and they now work! Long story short I don't know what was wrong but got around it this way.

In hind-sight distinguishing between *true* config variables and application parameters is probably not a bad idea so a Config and Globals class may be a good idea anyway.